# jquery prevent function running more than once

Tags: jquery, function

mySepsisTimer (a simple countdown timer) initiates once option select criteria (sepsis-six-sirs) are reached. But, if a user clicks on another select option after starting the timer function, a duplicate clock also runs. How can I prevent the mySepsisTimer function from running more than once, or reset it if the user clicks (or unselects) another one of the same (sepsis-six-sirs) options.

```
$('#sepsis-six-sirs input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
recalculateThisIsSepsis();
});

function recalculateThisIsSepsis(){
var sum = 0;
$("#sepsis-six-sirs input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
    sum+=parseInt($(this).val());
});

if (sum > 1) {
    mySepsisTimer();
}}
```

Comment: `var running = false; function foo() { if !running { do stuff } }`?

Comment: You should have posted `mySepsisTimer()` method in question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing [`$.Callbacks("once")`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/#once)

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks("once");

callbacks.add(mySepsisTimer);

$('#sepsis-six-sirs input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  recalculateThisIsSepsis();
});

function recalculateThisIsSepsis(){
  var sum = 0;
  $("#sepsis-six-sirs input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    sum+=parseInt($(this).val());
  });

  if (sum > 1) {
    callbacks.fire();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks 271314. Excellent idea. Almost there. No more duplicate clock but it doesn't reset if I unselect a triggering option. Still, much appreciated. Thanks againm.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple using on and off.

on() -> add an evend handler off() -> remove an event handler

Example:

```
$("#item li").on('click', function () {
    $(this).text('ITEM CLICKED')
    alert('CLICKED');

    //remove the event
    $(this).off("click")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to limit mySepsisTimer to 1 time, you can simply use a flag on on the global scope.

```
var onlyOneTimer = 0;

// ... The rest of your code ...

if (sum > 1 && onlyOneTimer == 0) {
     onlyOneTimer = 1;
     mySepsisTimer();
}}
```

It's not a "Best Practice" solution, but it's the simplest to understand.